# Cannot install new packges in Pycharm (Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1)

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I know this question has been posted a couple time before, but I have tried everything those threads have suggested (using a terminal, making sure pip is updated, making sure it is in the right folder, etc.) and I am still unable install new packages. Would anyone have any new suggestions, I'm at a loss at what to do at this point. Thank you very much.

[The error that I am encountering in both the terminal and in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYTjw.png)

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install <something> --no-cache-dir`? The error msg suggests that pip is trying to use a cached package but can't find it. (I'm just fishing here.)

Comment: I appreciate it, but I get the same error - any idea who I could reach out to for this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install `os` from PyPI — `os` is a module from the standard library.

Comment: it happens even when I try to install nonstandard library modules